# ORSSerialPort -- debug freezing in XCode

Tags: macos, serial-port, xcode5, orsserialport

I am writing an app that utilizes a USB to RS232 DB-9 serial dongle and the Prolific PL2303HX drivers (v.1.5.1).  I'm connecting to a device @ 9600 baud, with a 40-byte payload @ 10Hz.  The data typically *changes* every second; within my app I'm firing off a NSNotification every second with an updated data dictionary.  At no point do I send data to the device.

It's working swimmingly well... **except when attempting to debug** in XCode 5.0.2 under OS 10.9.1.  If I pause at a breakpoint for any length of time (typically 3-5 seconds), my USB keyboard & mouse completely freeze.  Physically connecting and reconnecting don't help.  I have to VNC into my machine and quit XCode remotely at which point I gain KB/mouse control back.

Checking the documentation on the USB dongle, it has a 256-byte i/o buffer.  This is likely getting full/overflowing when debugging, which is somehow causing the driver and/or XCode to freeze.

One solution I suppose would be to always do the setup/reads/teardown of my `ORSSerialPort` on an alternate thread, but I'm not sure if that'll fix my debug issues.

Any ideas how to alleviate this issue?

Comment: I haven't seen this before, nor do I have a solution, unfortunately. However, interacting with ORSSerialPort entirely in the background is very unlikely to fix the problem, for a number of reasons. For whatever it's worth, my experience with Prolific's drivers has been pretty bad, including a nasty tendency to hang with no recourse other than a forced reboot (via the power button!). I'd recommend getting ahold of an FTDI-based adapter and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I found an older (supposedly Win-only) FTDI v4.00 adapter I had laying around here, installed their v2.2.18 drivers (under 10.9.2)... and *drumroll* NO MORE FREEZES!  (If I block code flow via debug, the driver eventually pauses the data -- assumedly when its 384-byte input buffer is full -- but it resumes nicely after that).  Thanks so much -- I guess to Prolific drivers aren't so... prolific.

Comment: Glad to hear it! There are Mac drivers for all USB to serial adapters, even if they claim to be Windows only. I try to steer people away from Prolific's stuff, but they're so prolific that it's hard ;-).